# Resize image in CodeIgniter while uploading and save that resized image in directory

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to resize an image while uploading it, and save that resized image using CodeIgniter. I tried some code, but doesn't work. Also I want to know how to apply this in multiple files upload too.Can someone help

```
public function submited()
{
  //$this->load->library('image_lib');
  $config['upload_path'] = './images';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

  $this->load->library('upload',$config);

  if($this->upload->do_upload('myfile'))
  {
    $filedata = $this->upload->data();
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['allowed_types']='jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './images'; 
    $config['new_image'] = './images'; 
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE; 
    $config['width'] = 200;
    $config['height'] = 150; 
    $config['quality']   = 75;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear(); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper function. And call helper function with the uploaded image file path. It will replace your image with the new size.

```
public function submitd()
{
         $config['upload_path'] = './images';
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
         $this->load->library('upload',$config);
         if($this->upload->do_upload('myfile'))
        {
           $filedata = $this->upload->data();
           $this->resize_image($filedata['full_path']);
        }
}
//you can create this function in helper or in same controller.
function resize_image($file_path) {
  $CI =& get_instance();
    // Set your config up
    $config['image_library']    = "gd2";      
    $config['source_image']     = $file_path;      
    $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;      
    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;     
    $config['new_image'] = $file_path; 
    $config['width'] = "320";      
    $config['height'] = "240";  
    $config['thumb_marker']=FALSE;
    $CI->load->library('image_lib');

    $CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
    // Do your manipulation

    if(!$CI->image_lib->resize())
    {
       $CI->image_lib->display_errors();  
    } 
    $CI->image_lib->clear(); 

}
```

Comment: yesssss    i trieddd... it was not working..and i didnt undrstand well

Comment: @HHHHHH it's simple when your file is uploaded give it's uploaded path to the  resize_image() function. and you can simply get path by $filedata['full_path']. I have mentioned in the answer. Did you understand?

Comment: OMGGG ITS WORKSSS NOWW.....yesss thanksssss...now i understood..it looked complicated for me first   thanks for help.

Comment: can i apply this for multiple file upload too?

Comment: when any file is uploaded than call resize_image() function. it will work.

Comment: but when its multiple upload.... its array.... it contain more than one image though

Comment: No problem with the array, all image uploaded one by one. when a single image is upload call that function.

Comment: Ahhh it worked for multiple image upload too.. you are  a life saver....thanks for this and you t ime

Answer (score 1):

To resize images use image library in codeigniter like this:

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['allowed_types']='jpg|jpeg|png|gif'; //extension to allow
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $file;    //your path uploaded file
    $config['new_image'] = $targetPath;     //path to save the new file
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE; //to maintain ratio of image
    $config['width'] = 200; // width to resize image
    $config['height'] = 150; 
    $config['quality']   = 75;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();  `
```

Comment: yes, first upload the file then resize it and if you don't need the original file you can unlink it.

Comment: Message: getimagesize(E:/xamp/htdocs/Code/images): failed to open stream: Permission denied  this is the error

Comment: Your original image is uploaded? What I understand is you have path is incorrect.

Comment: yessss.. the original picture is uploaded in the directory

Comment: Your source image should be complete path with image name. Also include library once.

Comment: thanksss error is gone..but still imageis not resized

Comment: this is the errorhoswing for resizing      The path to the image is not correct.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

Comment: Try this `if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
       $this->image_lib->display_errors();  
    }` and paste the error.

Comment: @Shubham Azad i have included the image uploading code in question

Comment: @SaniaIshaq yeaahh i tried that.. i have commented error just before your comment

Comment: check in phpinfo() your gd library is enabled.

Comment: @SaniaIshaq ''code/images/'' i gave source image path like this..is it okay?

Comment: Yes it should be with filename ,so it can pick the file and resize it.